# How do I separate the user section from my admin section?

Tags: angular, module, division

I want to know if creating modules in angular is enough to separate the user and admin sections of my project or do I need to make separate projects?

Comment: Hello, you should take a look at the documentation first: [https://angular.io/guide/router](https://angular.io/guide/router) with its example [https://stackblitz.com/angular/aepvpqmoqaj](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aepvpqmoqaj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate User and Admin to two projects if

- You are concerned about the security - In case a user tries to tamper with the frontend code base and accesses something within Admin Code which would be a security Risk
- If either user or admin sections suffer more changes than the other and downtime with admin deployment would affect your users site availability
- You need to keep your user facing module lightweight, separating the admin module should shed some weight and make it easier to load over the network
- You have already built the user module and refactoring code for the admin module would be a herculean task
- If the UI/UX requirements of Admin/User modules conflict with each other(low priority)

3rd point workaround  - If you plan to use Progressive Web Applications(PWA) in your application. Conversion of your app into PWA is very easy. Please refer [Angular-PWA](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started)

4th point workaround - Follow a scalable folder structure that would allow you to integrate more modules in the future [Angular-Folder Structure](https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7)

Comment: Thank you I was thinking along the lines of point number 1 just like you said but I think point number 2 also applies. Thank you once again.